# Is Judaism Fascism?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, fascism is a regime that exalts nation above the individual.

Many associate Nazism, for example,  with fascism.

And yet, considering the morning blessings, the blessings relating to the nation (the community or at least the congregation) seem to take precedence over those of the individual in terms of order of appearance. The same type of order preference is also found, for example, with parshat VaYakhel and Pekudei. Also in the order of the korbanot community comes before individual.

> וִיהִי רָצון מִלְּפָנֶיךָ ה' אֱלהֵינוּ וֵאלהֵי אֲבותֵינוּ שֶׁתַּרְגִּילֵנוּ בְּתורָתֶךָ. וְדַבְּקֵנוּ בְּמִצְותֶיךָ. וְאַל תְּבִיאֵנוּ לא לִידֵי חֵטְא. וְלא לִידֵי עֲבֵרָה וְעָון. וְלא לִידֵי נִסָּיון. וְלא לִידֵי בִזָּיון. וְאַל תַּשְׁלֶט בָּנוּ יֵצֶר הָרָע. וְהַרְחִיקֵנוּ מֵאָדָם רָע וּמֵחָבֵר רָע. וְדַבְּקֵנוּ בְּיֵצֶר הַטוב וּבְמַעֲשים טובִים. וְכף אֶת יִצְרֵנוּ לְהִשְׁתַּעְבֶּד לָךְ. וּתְנֵנוּ הַיּום וּבְכָל יום לְחֵן וּלְחֶסֶד וּלְרַחֲמִים בְּעֵינֶיךָ וּבְעֵינֵי כָל רואֵינוּ. וְתִגְמְלֵנוּ חֲסָדִים טובִים. בָּרוּךְ אַתָּה ה' הַגּומֵל חֲסָדִים טובִים לְעַמּו יִשרָאֵל.

יְהִי רָצון מִלְּפָנֶיךָ ה' אֱלהַי וֵאלהֵי אֲבותַי שֶׁתַּצִּילֵנִי הַיּום וּבְכָל יום מֵעַזֵּי פָנִים וּמֵעַזּוּת פָּנִים. מֵאָדָם רָע. וּמֵחָבֵר רָע. וּמִשָּׁכֵן רָע. וּמִפֶּגַע רָע. וּמִשּטָן הַמַּשְׁחִית. מִדִּין קָשֶׁה וּמִבַּעַל דִּין קָשֶׁה. בֵּין שֶׁהוּא בֶן בְּרִית וּבֵין שֶׁאֵינו בֶן בְּרִית

In that context, is Torah observant Judaism equated with [fascism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fascism)?

If not, why not? Is the problem with how fascism is defined? Or is the concept of the nation taking precedence over the individual in agreement with the Torah perspective?

Comment: valamalshinim applies to those making this claim

Comment: Your entire basis in Judaism for saying it's fascist is the claim that "considering the morning blessings, the blessings relating to the nation (the community or at least the congregation) seem to take precedence over those of the individual". Providing evidence of that claim would make your question much stronger, as would providing evidence that the morning blessings are the one thing to look at when examining whether Judaism is fascist. (If you're wondering why people downvoted, well, that's why _this_ person did, anyway.)

Comment: I voted to close this question because the word fascism is not appropriate

Comment: This question is not logical. You are asking whether a 4,000 year religion is a type of 20th-century nationalism.

Comment: Is Chemistry Communism?

Comment: Fascism is a name and has an Etymology, a movement created by Mussolini. Your dictionary is not good. The definition has not to do with Judaism.

Comment: In case it may be off the radar for some people, this charge is being leveled more and more frequently toward Israel both in language at the UN and even among certain politicians in America. In the end, it seems prudent to consider a well reasoned response to this question. I have added a link to the Wikipedia page explaining what it means and it isn’t about something limited to the 20th century. There have just been plenty of negative examples of fascist groups in the last century.

Comment: @sabbahillel A malshin is a charge made by a Jew. The people making this type of statement (about fascism) today are, as far as I have seen or heard, non-Jews.

Comment: vechol hachoshvim alai ra'ah @YaacovDeane

Comment: *fascism is a regime that exalts nation above the individual* - According to your own (mis)interpretation of the dictionary's definition, one might be tempted to think that *patriotism* might count as fascism as well (!)

Answer (score 6):

Judaism is a religion, not a regime, nation state or an ethnic group. The whole concept of a  regime that exalts nation above the individual doesn't apply to non-regimes.

Comment: Judaism is a relationship between a people (individual and collective) and Hashem

Answer (score 3):

Judaism does not place the nation above the individual, or the individual above the nation.  Judaism achieves a delicate balance between individual rights and community rights.  Here are two examples among many.

(1) To emphasize individual rights, the Torah asserts a person’s right to have enjoyed life before dying:

> [Before going to war] the officers shall speak to the people, saying, 
>   If one of you has built a new house, and has not yet dedicated it, let him go and return to his house, lest he die in the battle, and another man dedicates it.
>   And if one of you has planted a vineyard, and has not yet eaten of it, let him also go and return to his house, lest he die in the battle, and another man eats of it.
>   And if one of you has betrothed a wife, and has not yet married her, let him go and return to his house, lest he die in the battle, and another man marries her. [Deuteronomy 20:5-7]

(2) And to assert community rights, Joshua laid down restrictions on land ownership for the sake of the community, including [Baba Kama 80b-81a]:

-The community has the right to benefit from a new water source, even if discovered in private land.

-The community has the right to fish in Lake Kinneret, as long as it does not interfere with navigation.

-The community has the right of pasture in private land that is unfarmed.

-The community has the right of free passage on private land, including relieving oneself.

-Everyone has the right to be buried where he dies, even if on private 
land.

(3) If anything, there is a slight tilt towards the individual:

> Whoever destroys one life is considered as if he destroyed an entire world; and whoever saves one life is considered as if he saved an entire world… [Sanhedrin Y 4:1 (22a)]  So everyone must say: The world was created for my sake. [Mishna, Sanhedrin 37a]

Comment: @MauriceMizrachi All of the details you are bringing out are relevant and worth noting. But as you present it, Judaism is just another political/legal philosophy, better in some ways and worse in others. Please look at the link I added clarifying what fascism is and means. I am sure that you can see many parallels to what fascism means/is within Torah observant Judaism (see Mishneh Torah, laws of Kings for example). That said, there is a clear difference which needs to be pointed out. Do you see it?